# How to gzip output from map reduce on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the FileOutputWriter to write a file to Cloud Storage which I would like to compress. Is there a way to gzip the file using the Cloud Storage API? It looks like the gsutil command line utility lets you do this, but I haven't come across a way to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python zipfile library that's included:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile